# Передача данных из PHP в JS

Tags: javascript, php

Итак тестирую следующий код из подобного обсуждения, в папке сайта один файл index.html следующего содержания:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <? $var = "Hello, world"; ?>
<script>
var a = "<? echo $var ?>";
alert(a);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

ожидаю что появится всплывающее уведомление с Hello World, но появляется следующее[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Файлик должен иметь расширение .php? =)

Comment: помогло, но мне нужно передать переменную в HTML файле

Comment: если используется Apache, добавить в начало файла `.htaccess` строку `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`  для mod_php или `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` php-cgi. Или вообще доставить строку по ajax

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Файл `index.php` - обратите внимание на расширение файла и запускать нужно на сервере - локальном или в инете - но на сервере.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <?php  
        $var = "Hello, world"; 
        echo $var;
        ?>
<script>
var a = "<?=$var?>";
alert(a);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: запускаю на сервер. Но вот с расширением сложновато. Мне важно чтобы выполнялось в HTML

Comment: Тогда Вам нужно сконфигурировать сервер так, чтобы он исполнял файлы html, как php, или через включение iframe или еще что подобное

Comment: Благодарю! Помогло

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад!